# 2D Vector of Doubles editing causing crash

Tags: c++, 2d-vector

I am working on a C++ class that consists of a 2D Vector of Doubles. I am about to create the 2D Vector but when I try to edit the values inside of it, the program crashes. I have tried using the [][] operator and setting it equal to myDub and I have tried using a class like myMat.editSlot(i,j,myDub) and both have caused the program to crash.

//n == # of rows and cols (all matrices are square)
//infile opens the file properly

```
mat my_mat(n,n);

// Read input data
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        double myDub;
        inFile >> myDub;

        my_mat.editSlot(i,j,myDub);
    }
}
```

and here is the class:

```
class mat
{

    mat( int x , int y ) {
        int row = x;
        int col = y;
        vector<vector<double>> A( row , vector<double>( row , 0 ) );


        for ( int i = 0; i<row; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j<col; j++ )
            {
                cout << setw( 6 ) << A[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    void editSlot( int x , int y , double val ) {
        A[x][y] = val;
    }
    vector<vector<double>> A;

private:
    int n;

};
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. One the hopefully *builds*.

Comment: Oh and you should probably think about where `A` is declared, in what scope you have it. *And* what happens if `row != col` (considering the initialization of the ***local*** variable `A`).

Comment: Maybe you meant to make the vector have `col` columns, instead of `row` columns

Comment: Okay, so I updated so it should be the minimal amount of code needed to replicate my issue. Row is always  == Col because all of the data files we are given are square. What is wrong with where it's placed? Is it not a member of the class?

Comment: @M.M no, the rows and cols are identical.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude could you give a small example of how I could do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that the way you're initializing `A` is wrong.  Try something like this:

```
A = vector<vector<double>>( row , vector<double>( row , 0 ) );
```

Another thing to consider both the constructor and the edit function aren't declared public.

Comment: While this will solve the immediate problem asked about, it is still a good (or bad, depending on point of view) example of copy-paste programming. By just copy-pasting the line and doing a slight edit, you missed a subtle but crucial bug that will happen if `row != col`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - The OP has already mentioned that the data is strongly typed and consistent and row will always equal col.  In this case that is worrying about nothing.

Comment: While true for this specific test case, if the possibility to use some feature exists then someday it will be used.

Comment: At a certain point people have to be expected to use their brains.  Since the limitations are clearly stated, anyone not paying attention to them are doing so at their own peril.  It's kind of ridiculous to be constantly trying to moddle coddle people instead of letting them think for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem that leads to crush is that you change size of a temporal vector A in your constructor while A vector that you declared as a field in your class object is not touched.
I suggest doing something like this:

```
mat(int x,int y) : A(y,vector<double>(x,0)) {
 int row = x;
 int col = y;  
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(6)<<A[i][j];
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }
}
```

In this case you won't hide your A field in class with temporal A object in constructor function.
Also please pay attention not to swap x and y in your functions. For example, you have an error in your editSlot function:

```
void editSlot( int x , int y , double val ) {
    A[x][y] = val;
}
```

, it should be:

```
A[y][x] = val;
```

according to constructor.